# Detecting existence of empty XML node attribute with XPathNavigator

Tags: .net, xpath

Is there an easy way to detect the existence of an **empty** attribute on an XPathNavigator XML node (e.g. `<node>` vs. `<node attribute="">`)? `Node.GetAttribute` returns an empty string either way. The only thing I can think of is checking the `Node.OuterXML` property, which seems like a really dumb approach.

(Note: the node won't *actually* be empty, so I can't just use `Node.HasAttributes`.)

Comment: If possible, I would recommend using LINQ to XML.

Comment: That might be doable, but in testing LINQ in the early stages of this project, I found it added a lot of overhead compared to just parsing the XML directly. It's definitely useful in some situations, though, so I may look into it some more.

Comment: I don't understand, using LINQ to XML, is “just parsing the XML directly” too, it's just different API (and IMHO better one). I don't know why would it create a performance overhead. If you were comparing it with something like `XmlReader`, that would be different, but you aren't.

Comment: @svick: I'd have to go back and re-try...I did preliminary evaluations on the various XML parsing options when I was starting and picked the one that seemed the fastest and that fit my needs, but I can't claim to be significantly familiar with any of them, as this is my first foray into .NET territory, so perhaps I was doing something less-than-optimal or thought there was some feature missing that was actually there. At this point, I couldn't tell you. (And yeah, my wording was a little inaccurate there, as using *any* parsing API is inherently not parsing the XML directly.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use XPath:

```
elem.SelectSingleNode("@attribute")
```

This returns `null`, if the the attributte `attribute` doesn't exist, and another `XPathNavigator` with `NodeType` of `Attribute` and `Value` containing an empty string if the attribute exists, but is empty.